# Maven : Dependencies Management

Tags: maven, executable-jar

I already saw lot of post related to this question, but hard to figure out the best approach of doing this.  I am having a maven project having two dependencies (A.Jar) and (B.Jar) in maven central repostories. I want to create a runnable jar. Which is the best approach in doing this and how to do this  ? An example will be helpful. (sample POM.XML)

thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) via a predefined descriptor:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>    
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Via the above you can do simply:

```
mvn clean package
```

which results in having a file `target/whatever-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` which is exactly what you like to get.